# How do I install caching module in my php website

Tags: php, database, caching

I'm relatively new to php (just starting to get away from one-click install thing in wordpress).. The fact that Wordpress has wasted too much of my time in learning the basic programming level languages like PHP, JS etc.. Probably, I'd have learnt to custom program myself a lot (by now) if I were never introduced to wordpress or any other cms.. Yes, wordpress/cms starters can become a good developers but I think that's a bad start for anyone wanting to be a good developers in the future. It's indirect way of learning to code, I guess.

Ignore the above phrases, wordpress guys :). Now, the real help I'm seeking from stackoverflow community is - I want to install [php fast cache](http://www.phpfastcache.com/)  in to my custom built php website.. With the help of hiring some developers and myself, I'm able to build a basic community website which has chat system enabled that can generate lots of database queries, so I found this phpfastcache which promises to bring down thousands of db queries to one single query which has a potential of decreasing the page loads substantially.. I've downloaded the file from github and uploaded the file into my server root directory.

Now as there is not much of documentations in the website, I'm not sure how can I successfully implement it.. I tried putting some codes in config.php, functions.ph and the specific pages (but I'd want to cache the entire site) as per available instructions in the website but it seems not working..

If someone can help me or guide me briefly, I'd be thankful for the volunteered help.. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Comment: Holy wall of irrelevant text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you use composer, if you don't will be a good time to get onto composer.

https://getcomposer.org/

Once you have composer installed you can just install the FastCache using composer by running this command:

composer require phpFastCache/phpFastCache

and you can just implement it like the Example on phpfastcache.com

Hope this helps.